# Copy innerHTML from one item in a list to the content of an element

Tags: javascript, onclick, innerhtml

Here's what I'm hoping to do: I have a list of menu items. When one of these items are clicked on, I want a javascript function to take the text in that list item and place it in a div somewhere else on the page.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3BF4q/

```
function setText() {
document.getElementById("selected").innerHTML = this.innerHTML; 
};
```

I don't know much about JavaScript, so I'm sure the problem is simple.

Also, if there's a similar question on stackoverflow please send me a link to it and I'll remove this question.

Comment: Did my answer help you at all??  You were just not passing the element into the function....hence it didn't know which element you were clicking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the element to the function...so that it knows which `<a>` tag you clicked.

So in your HTML you add `this` as a function parameter

```
<a href="#" onclick="setText(this);">
```

And in your Javascript...`(e)` in this case, refers to that element now.

```
function setText(e){
document.getElementById('selected').innerHTML = e.innerHTML;
 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/3BF4q/4/)

Here it is using Jquery....just to show how much more compact it becomes...

```
<a href="#">
```

.

```
$('a').click(function(){$('#selected').html($(this).html());});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/3BF4q/1/)

Comment: And to set it to only capture the links in the list using jquery I change `$('a')` to `$('.link')`... neato

Comment: Simple, just add the class specifier...$('a.link') in this case....http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/3BF4q/9/

Comment: Thanks for your help... I was editing my answer when you answered. lol

Comment: Jquery can select by class , id, or element....so if you wanna select a tag with an id, its $('#idgoeshere'), if you wanna select a class its, $('.classgoeshere'), and just an element is $('p'), or $('a'), or $('div') or whatever HTML element you want....if you have elements with the same class, but you wanna just select say...the divs with class test.....then you append the element to the front....$('div.test') that will select only the divs, even if you have some <a>'s with class test